# Crystal Reports Filter by Most Recent Date of Field

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report I am creating through an ODBC connection.  The report includes several invoices, where each invoice has several products.  There is also a table which contains all the historical price changes for each product (field: unit-price).  Currently there are duplicate product records being pulled, one for each time there was a price change.  Therefore, I need to filter my data so that only the most recent unit-price is shown (date field: effective-date).  How can I do this via the "Select Expert?"

In short, show the product's unit-price for the most recent effective-date.

Thank you!

Comment: Unless you need all that data to be retrieved from the database, your report will generate more quickly if you can pull the most recent effective date from database only. It will likely not matter much if you have a small set to work with, but your approach does not scale well.

Comment: Is pulling only the most recent effective date from the database something I can do in Crystal then?

Comment: @user3616771: Why don't you create a stored procedure which brings you the correct results??

Comment: I do not have access to the database.  I figured out the solution.  In select expert you can choose to filter by "group."  In here I used "effective-date = maximum(effective-date, product)" and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a sql-expression field to get the most-recent effective date, then use this field in the record-selection formula.

```
// {%MAX_EFFECTIVE_DATE}
// most-likely you'll need to alias the table in the main report for this to work
(
SELECT Max(effective_date)
FROM   price_history
WHERE  product_id = price_history_alias.product_id
)
```

Record-selection formula:

```
{price_history_alias.effective_date}={%MAX_EFFECTIVE_DATE}
```

Comment: Can't believe I just now saw this.  I've never used a SQL Expression Field in CR and I keep getting an error for even the most basic queries.  Is it a syntax problem?  
  
    SELECT "effective-date"  
    FROM ("APPRISE"."PUB"."product_price")  
    WHERE ("product_price"."product-key" = '1004138')

Comment: You need to wrap everything in a pair of parentheses.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of doing it in select expert. group by effective date and set the ordering as `Descending`.

Comment: This still includes all the products in the dataset, making my calculations incorrect.

Comment: yes by this approach it includes all.. if you don't require create a parameter and give the value of what need to be retrived while running the report and provide that parameter in select expert.